# Remove space before footer in Microsoft Word on Mac

Tags: ms-word

I want to remove space before footer in word file. I am using 15.37 version of Word on Macbook. I have tried the method mentioned in https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010se-word/how-can-i-remove-the-space-above-the-footnote/6bcb9853-74d9-41c0-afd3-9a5c3394171c?page=1&auth=1 but still not solved.

I want to remove space mentioned in red box and it only appears on the first page only.

[image]

I have also attached the screenshot of my paragraph setting. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to Header and Footer section in Word. Adjust `Footer from Bottom` in the top-right corner. It will reduce the space between actual text and footer section.